# how to get all product collection using product name like and price ascending in magento?

Tags: php, magento, product

I have different affiliate products with almost same name in database, how can we do a price comparison of those products in product details page? Can anyone help me with the shortest way?

I tried this

```
$product_id = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();

$obj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

$_product = $obj->load($product_id);

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection(); 

$collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', ['like' => $_product->getName().'%']);
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a good way to go about it to me, but you could probably simplify your code to just:

```
$_product = Mage::registry('current_product');
$_collection = $_product->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('name', ['like' => $_product->getName() . '%']);
```

Comment: Thank you,can you please suggest how can we add order by price ASC along with product name to the same product collection?

Comment: @Surekha - For future reference, you should not ask followup questions on valid answers to your original question. There are multiple ways you could sort by price so it should be a separate question, but [this answer should do the trick](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8874011/1737136).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the code below is working for me:

```
$productName = Mage::registry('current_product')->getName();

$categoryId = Mage::registry('current_product')->getCategoryId();

$manufacturerId = Mage::registry('current_product')->getManufacturer();

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId); 

$productslist = $products->getProductCollection()                       
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer',$manufacturerId)
->addAttributeToFilter('name', ['like' => $productName . '%'])
->setOrder('price', 'ASC');
```